# Как написать рекурсивную функцию, которая принимает число и возвращает булево значение

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Никак не удается понять суть и мыслить на уровне рекурсии

**Task:**
Нужно написать функцию, которая принимает число, если число четная, то возвращает `true`, иначе при нечетном числе возвращает `false`

Мой простой и примитивный способ

```
function isEven(num){

    if (num % 2 == 0) {
      return true
    }
    return false;

}
```

А вот рекурсивно-то как?? Я понимаю, что она  возвращает саму себя

```
      function isEven(num){
         return  isEven(num){
        //как дальше, дайте пинка
            if (){

          } 

    } 
}
```

Comment: Тут рекурсии нет

Comment: *А вот рекурсивно-то как?* Ой, проблему нашёл... `if num=0 return true elseif num=1 return false else return isEven(num-2)`

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсия - это функции, которые вызывают сами себя.

Простой пример:
Факториал означает — умножить все числа от 1 до n. Так что, 3! это 1 * 2 * 3. Давайте напишем функцию факториала.

```js
const factorial = (n) => {
  if (n === 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return n * factorial(n-1);
  }
}

const answer = factorial(3);
```

Вот основные требования рекурсии:
1. Простой базовый случай или терминальный сценарий. Простыми словами, **когда остановиться**.  В нашем примере это была 1: мы остановили вычисление факториала, когда достигли 1.
2. **Правило двигаться** по рекурсии, углубляться. В нашем случае, это было n * factorial(n-1).

Вот результат:

```js
factorial(3);
3 * factorial(2);
3 * 2 * factorial(1);
3 * 2 * 1;
3 * 2;
6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос хоть и давний и немного странный по своим требованиями, но, если бы у меня потребовали именно с рекурсией и никак иначе, то я бы написал так:

```js
const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200 - 100);
console.log(num);

const isEven = (num) => {
  num = Math.abs(num);

  const checkNumber = (num) => {
    if (num === 0) return true;
    if (num === 1) return false;

    return checkNumber(num - 2);
  }

  return checkNumber(num);
}

console.log(isEven(num));
```